# VB CompileAssemblyFromSource Win 8.1 error

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-8.1, codedom

Googled problem, but seems like I'm the first who encountered it yet...
Same of code compiles in Windows 7 & 8 environment, but fails in Windows 8.1.

`Dim x As Object = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel`

If it is like that - win7 and win8 compile it with no problems.
Once it's in the win8.1 - it fails due to `'Forms' is not a member of 'Windows'`.
IF I specify it as `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel` - it then compiles without errors.

Code is just copy-pasted from IDE in win7 to IDE in win8.1, so imports etc. are totally the same.
Frameworks on both machines are updated to latest versions.
MSVS says that in both cases it uses `System.dll, v4.0.0.0`.

Can anyone help to understand such differences in behavior in win 7&8 vs 8.1?

Comment: Nothing is different in 8.1.  Clearly you already have an identifier named "Windows" in your source code.  You avoid such accidents by consistently using the full namespace name, like Globals.System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel.  It is a mouthful that a compiler does not mind.

Comment: I understand that nothing _should_ be different. But, then again, something differs, as in 8.1 I have to specify the `System` namespace.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uu6rSCDE - here's the code that can reproduce the bug in w8.1 but works fine in w7 and w8